# What are the boilerplate codes in Activity and fragments (Android)?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The idea behind dagger-android is to reduce the boilerplate needed to inject objects. To be even more specific, **the idea is to reduce that boilerplate code in Fragments, Activities** or any other Android framework classes that are instantiated by the OS.[link](https://proandroiddev.com/using-dagger-android-in-a-multi-module-project-e751afaa53ba)

So, here as i made the bold text, what are the boilerplate code in android and how dagger2 reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it wrong Dagger does not meant to remove boiler plate code (It does in a way but it certainly not build for that purpose).  That's what a library serve it perform the all the heavy lifting and provide us easier ways to implement the feature .

The feature dagger provide is [Dependency Inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) its the `D` from `SOLID principle` .
Dagger is a Dependency injection framework which takes care of providing dependencies which the scopes provided its annotation base so its runtime safe. Its maintains a Dependency Graph of whole application the dependency we provides in our modules and inject them as they needed . That's all it does So yeah now you do not have to create objects in Activity/Fragment if you inject them if that's what you call boiler plate then you won't need it anymore . But IMO its not a boiler plate . Dependency Inversion principle Also make it easier to write code in TDD fashion.

You can build your own DI module if u don't want to use Dagger but why?